# Bot Framework error when doing context.Wait(): Value cannot be null. Parameter name: wait

Tags: c#, bots, botframework

I have a bot with a "root" dialog that runs child dialogs using `context.Call()` or `context.Forward()` depending on the user's choice, like so:

```
context.Call(new QuestionsDialog(), ChildDialogComplete);
```

After the child dialog exits, the control is passed to this method, `ChildDialogComplete`. It outputs a prompt and waits for the user's reply.

```
    public async Task ChildDialogComplete(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> argument)
    {
        var unnecessaryTemp = await argument;
        var restartPrompt = context.MakeMessage();
        restartPrompt.Text = "Say \"hi\" again if I can help with anything else!";
        await context.PostAsync(restartPrompt);
        context.Wait(MainScreenSelectionReceived);
    }
```

When debugging, the last line of the method with `context.Wait()` causes this exception in the emulator:

> Exception: **System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: wait** at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.Fiber1.-PollAsync>d__13.MoveNext()
>
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.Wait 2.Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.IAwaiter.GetResult() at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Chain.LoopDialog1.d__3.MoveNext()
>
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>
> ...and so on

This error doesn't occur when `ChildDialogComplete` is run "naturally", when a dialog exits. It only occurs when I try to call this method manually, from another part of the root dialog, like so:

```
ChildDialogComplete(context, argument);
```

Where `context` and `argument` are the two standard parameters of methods in an IDialog (`IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> argument`).

The `argument` was previously `await`ed before being passed to the method. But I assume this is not an issue because the exception occurs at the `context.Wait()` line which seems unrelated to `IAwaitable`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot pass the awaited value to a method expecting an `IAwaitable<T>`. Also, you are doing await twice into the argument if that's the case (one before calling the method, and another one inside the method)

Refactor your code to extract all the logic inside the `ChildDialogComplete` method so you end up with two methods, one receiving the `IAwaitable<T>` and the other one just the value. The one receiving the IAwaitable should await the argument and call the new method.

However, you are not using the argument in that method, so if that would be the case; you don't need to refactor and you could just call the `ChildDialogComplete` with `null` for the `IAwaitable<T>` parameter after removing the `await argument` call of your method

```
ChildDialogComplete(context, null);
```

Comment: Hey , can  help me with this part of code First : https://pastebin.com/eqV0F8wn , second : https://pastebin.com/WVLjG24i . I am facing two errors while try to change await and trying other combinations . "Activity ID cannot be Null" and " Value cannot be null. Parameter name: wait ". Can you plz help

Comment: post a question please.

Comment: The same problem discussed above. thats y i commented here ,